# Trying to capitalise first letter of words after a hyphen in bash on mac

Tags: regex, macos, perl

I am trying to use sed to change expressions such as

```
my-word-now
```

to

```
my-Word-Now
```

i.e. Capitalise any word after a hyphen but not the first word which is before the hyphen.  There can be any number of hyphens.

I am trying to do this on the mac's bash shell which I believe does not support /u for a sed capitalisation. So I try perl.

The closest I can get is:

```
echo my word now | perl -pe 's/\S+/\u$&/g'
```

It gives me `My Word Now`

But if I try:

```
echo my-word-now | perl -pe 's/\-+/\u$&/g'
```

It just gives me: `my-word-now`

any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
s/-\K(\w)/\U$1/g
```

(or skip the parentheses and just use $& if this is really for a oneliner).

Note that \U uppercases; \u titlecases, which is a little different.

Comment: @BreakoBreako The pattern before the `\K` is matched as normal, but `\K` resets the matched substring. Because of this, the substitution does not remove the `-`.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution `s/\S+/\u$&/g` matches all non-space characters, and then substitutes them with the first letter uppercased. Written more cleanly with captures, this would be `s/(\S+)/\u$1/g`.

The substitution `s/\-+/\u$&/g` matches all sequences of hyphens, and then tries to uppercase those! Hyphens do not have an uppercase form, so this does not work.

A better solution: Let's match right behind each hyphen `(?<=-)`, then capture a single letter `(\w)`, and subsitute that letter with the capitalized form: `\u$1`. Together:

```
s/(?<=-)(\w)/\u$1/g
```